# Shell script that watches HTML templates and compiles with Handlebars

Tags: bash, shell, templates, compilation, handlebars.js

I'm trying to create a script that watches my HTML template files in a directory and when it notify's changes, it compiles the template. I can't get it working, this is what I got:

```
#!/bin/sh
while FILENAME=$(inotifywait --format %w -r templates/*.html)
do
  COMPILED_FILE=$(echo "$FILENAME" | sed s/templates/templates\\/compiled/g | sed s/.html/.js/g)
  handlebars $FILENAME -f $COMPILED_FILE -a
done
```

I use [inotifywait](http://linux.die.net/man/1/inotifywait) to watch the current dir, although I want it also to check for sub directories. The compiled files then need to be saved in a sub directory called `templates/compiled` with optionally the sub directory.

So `templates/foo.html` needs to be compiled and stored as `templates/compiled/foo.js`

So `templates/other/foo.html` needs to be compiled and stored as `templates/compiled/other/foo.js`

As you can see I tried to watch the directoy and replace the `templates/` name with `templates/compiled`.

Any help is welcome!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*A few observations, then a solution:*

Passing the argument `-r templates/*.html` only matches *.html* files in `templates/` — not in `templates/other/`. Instead we're going to do `-r templates` which notifies us of changes to any file **anywhere** under `templates`.

If you don't use `inotifywait` in `--monitor` mode, you will miss any files that are changed in the brief period that `handlebars` is running (which could happen if you save all your open files at once). Better to do something like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
watched_dir="templates"
while read -r dirname events filename; do
    printf 'File modified: %s\n' "$dirname$filename"
done < <(inotifywait --monitor --event CLOSE_WRITE --recursive "$watched_dir")
```

Then, as for transforming the paths, you could do something like:

```
$ dirname=templates/other/
$ echo "${dirname#*/}"
other/
$ echo "$watched_dir/compiled/${dirname#*/}"
templates/compiled/other/
$ filename=foo.html
$ echo "${filename%.html}"
foo
$ echo "${filename%.html}.js"
foo.js
$ echo "$watched_dir/compiled/${dirname#*/}${filename%.html}.js" 
templates/compiled/other/foo.js
```

Notice that we can leverage [Bash's builtin parameter expansion](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/pe#substring_removal) — no need for `sed`.

Putting it all together, we get:

```
#!/bin/bash
watched_dir="templates"
while read -r dirname events filename; do
    [[ "${filename##*.}" != 'html' ]] && continue

    output_path="$watched_dir/compiled/${dirname#*/}${filename%.html}.js"
    handlebars "$dirname$filename" -f "$output_path" -a
done < <(inotifywait --monitor --event CLOSE_WRITE --recursive "$watched_dir")
```

Comment: Thank you for the great explanation , your genius!